# How to put comments in device tree source files

Tags: comments, device-tree

How do i put multiline or single line comments in device tree source files. I couldn't find it anywhere. 
Does the default c way of using comments work?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Does the default c way of using comments work?

Yes, use `/* comment */`.

---

**ADDENDUM**

I've also used C preprocessor `#if 0` and `#endif` directives to quickly disable (or enable) multiple lines of a node during testing.
I have not seen any conditional directives in DT files elsewhere, so such use may be frowned upon.

Comment: yeah i was about to post the same answer for my own question. 
Got some hands on experience with using device tree now and i was sure we use the comments /* my comment */. Thanks sawdust.

Answer (score 12):

Here is what [devicetree documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/booting-without-of.txt) says:

> The format of the .dts "source" file is "C" like, supports C and C++
>   style comments.

So you can use both

```
/* multiline (C style)
   comments */
```

and

```
// single line (C++ style) comments,
```

although the latter is not commonly used for some reason.

Comment: *"the latter is not commonly used for some reason"* -- The reason would be that C++ style comments are not part of the [(Linux) kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html).